# How can I separate. to my database variable?

Tags: php, html

I have few data in mysql(link,description,date,del(delete status))

now Im taking this data from mysql with my code. But I wanna show my data's like this photo
as you can see all data's looks clear and separate.

[image]

Im using this sql code for take these data's

```
 $sql = "SELECT `vLink` ,`vDescription`, `vDate` FROM `video_table`
```

But when I use my code output looks like
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8f9IiUXA4EMYSQL | How to auto date time with MYSQL?2021-01-17 02:32:55`

now I can use 3 sql code(for link,description,date) to take my all data's and I can put list each by each but Im wondering have we easy way?

thats my code

```
$sql = "SELECT `vLink` ,`vDescription`, `vDate` FROM `video_table` WHERE `vDel` = 0 ";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $Vdatas = array();
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $Vdatas[] = $row;
      }
  }

//print_r($Vdatas);

 foreach ($Vdatas[0] as $data) {
     echo $data;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need some HTML and CSS

Comment: my question is not about html, css. my output is pringting like 1 variable but actually its 3 variable.  its printing vlink+vDescription+vdate same time. Idk why @Shadow deleted mysql tags in question Its a mysql question.

Comment: It's printing them all together because you don't have any formatting. You just echo them with nothing in between. It's not clear what you expect to happen instead? `echo $data;` prints just the value, with no spaces, no new lines, or anything like that. So you repeat that command in a loop, then of course you get all the outputs joined together on the screen. Changing that kind of presentation to something better is what html is for. I don't see what mysql has to do with it. Mysql just gets the raw data. How you show that data is the job of HTML and CSS (helped by PHP).

Comment: sir , I think you didnt understand my problem but it can be bc of my english.  I have 4 different data in my table. pls check photo I put in question (my table in mysql). I just wanna print vlink in my table. not others. but when I try to print , its printing all of them.

Comment: btw I fixed my problem        ` echo "<tr><td>" . $row["vLink"]. "</td><td>" . $row["vDescription"] . "</td><td>"
            . $row["vDate"]. "</td></tr>";
`

Comment: So, you fixed the issue using html. No sql, no mysql, no databases. But your question is surely not about html :)

Comment: $row["x"] ,   fixed my problem. I guess its in php problem category not html :) Im new and sorry about absurd tags @Shadow :) btw Do I get points for solving my own question? Or is it just when solving other people's problem? :)

Comment: No, it's HTML. `<tr><td>` is HTML. You made a HTML table. You used PHP to create the HTML, but it's the HTML which is used by the web browser to decide how to display the data on the page. I think you need to take some more time to understand the different technologies used in a web application. And specifically you should take a HTML tutorial

Comment: You can have points for solving your own question yes...but only if you write the solution properly in the Answers area, below this section. And you might want to add some thanks to the people who told you to solve it using HTML... :-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer